error in cmake, not able to link definiton of header files
I am building a project in C, the file structure is given below :
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── parsing.h
│   └── serial.h
├── lib
│   ├── parsing.c
│   └── serial.c
├── MCQs.txt
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── main.c
└── test
    ├── sbus_data
    └── sbus_generator.py


I am using cmake to compile the given project. So basically I have the source code in src/main.c, and I am using two libraries parsing.h and parsing.h in main.c. The definition of the functions in serial.h and parsing.h is in lib dir. My current CMake look like this :
project(R25 LANGUAGES C)
add_executable(MAIN src/main.c)
target_include_directories(MAIN PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

However I am getting an error in cmake that it does include the functions in main.c however,the definition of the function in lib dir is not linked, how do I tell cmake to use lib dir when building main.c

Your CMakeLists.txt lists nothing in lib.  Why would you expect the sources to be included in MAIN?

Yes I know that, I did try to add the lib dir, but I was unable to do it. Can you show me how to do it, or provide any CMake docs.

What's your attempt that isn't working after listing all the source files?  Did you check the documentation for add_executable and notice it can take multiple source files?

I modified 'add_executable', it works now thanks a lot!
